# Prevent modal from closing after re-render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside a Component, I have a Modal from which the user can do an update to some data through an API and then change the state of that main Component. Because there is a change in state, everything will re-render.

I would like to keep the modal open, so that I can show a success message.

The code would be something like this.

```
 const Main = () => {
    const [state, setState()] = useState();
    return (
    <Component state={state}>
       <Modal onButtonClick={() => {
           updateThroughApi().then(() => setState())} />
    </Component>
    )
}
```

When user clicks on modal's button, the state changes, and `Component` is re-rendered. Modal is rendered too, as it's inside.

I have thought of two possible solutions:

1. Move the modal outside of the component. This is a problem, as my actual code is not as simple as the example I posted. In my code, the modal opens on the click of a  button `B`, which is deep inside `Component`. So, if I move the modal out from `Component`, I would have to pass the status and the action to change status (e.g. [open, setOpen]) through  several components until button B (prop drilling).
2. Another solution: On the action `onButtonClick` I just do the API update, and use a new state `updated = true`; then, `onModalClose`, only if updated is true, I run `setState` so  `Component` is rendered just after the modal is closed. But this solution seems a hack to me. There must be a better way.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Full code please. Something is fundamentally wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is obviously going very wrong here, the Modal should not close. As a workaround you could do something like this:

```
const Main = () => {
    const [state, setState()] = useState();
    const modal = useMemo(() => (
       <Modal onButtonClick={() => {
           updateThroughApi().then(() => setState())} />
    ), [])

    return (
        <Component state={state}>{modal}</Component>
    )
}
```

Comment: You are right, something was wrong. In fact I was changing a condition so the modal was not rendered. Should I remove the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Modal` is re-rendering because your function passed as `onButtonClick` is redefined at every render.

So you have 2 options here:

1/ Keep your `Modal` inside your Component and use `useMemo`

```js
import { useMemo } from 'react'

const Main = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();
    const modal = useMemo(() => (
        <Modal onButtonClick={() => (
                updateThroughApi().then(() => setState())
            )}
        />
    ), [])

    return (
        <Component state={state}>
            {modal}
        </Component>
    )
}
```

Or 2/ Move your `Modal` outside your component and use combination of `memo` and `useCallback`

```js
import { memo, useCallback } from 'react'

const Main = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();
    const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => updateThroughApi().then(() => setState()), []);

    return (
        <Component state={state}>
            <Modal onButtonClick={onButtonClick} />
        </Component>
    )
}

const Modal = memo(({onButtonClick}) => {

})
```

So in this case, at every render, `memo` will compare if all `Modal` props are `===` from previous render, which is now the case, because memoization of `onButtonClick` with `useCallback`, and so your `Modal` component will not re-render

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo